# C code Compilation error

Tags: c, gcc

this is the  error that i have

```
mouse_cat.c:20: error: array type has incomplete element type
mouse_cat.c:20: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
mouse_cat.c:27: error: array type has incomplete element type
mouse_cat.c:27: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
```

and this is the source code

```
void enlever(char terrain [ ][ ],int x,int y)
  {
    terrain[y][x]=' ';
  }

//********************************************//

 void ajouter(char terrain [ ][ ],int x ,int y,int flag)
  {
   if(flag) 
    terrain[y][x]='C';
   else
    terrain[y][x]='S';
  }
```

and this is my declaration

```
#define x 23
#define y 22 

 char terrain [y][x];
```

i used Gcc (linux)

Comment: maybe with if(flag) { 
    terrain[y][x]='C';
  } else {
    terrain[y][x]='S';}

Comment: #define x 23 will cause huge troubles down the line..

Anywhere you have x the compiler will put 23..

Comment: so what i do ? !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The define macro has the following syntax:

`#define name replacer`

The first stage in compilation, the preprocessor stage handles all so-called preprocessor directives (lines starting with #), including this. In this case, it replaces all occurences of *name* with *replacer*. So, your function will look like `void enlever(char** terrain,int 23, int 22)` to actual compiler. Also, you may have variable names, for example, which contain the letter x or y. Those would be replaced too.

To avoid such situations, a coding standard suggest naming constants declared with #define with capital letters. But this is not enough, because the name *X* or *Y* is still possible to arise as a name of a variable or user defined data type, or even in a string. So you may use something like:

```
#define TERRAIN_LENGTH 23
#define TERRAIN_WIDTH 22
```

Do not forget that is a good practice to use constants instead of magical numbers (like in declaration `int terrain[22][23];` ), because they make your code much more easy to understand and mantain.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to:

```
#define TX 23
#define TY 22 

void enlever(char terrain [ ][TY],int x,int y)
 {
    terrain[y][x]=' ';
  }

//********************************************//

 void ajouter(char terrain [ ][TY],int x ,int y,int flag)
  {
   if(flag) 
    terrain[y][x]='C';
   else
    terrain[y][x]='S';
  }
```

Issue 1: The function formal parameters are replaced with the marco definitions.

Issue 2: The second and subsequent dimensions of an array parameter must be given:

Also see: [GCC: array type has incomplete element type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003270/gcc-array-type-has-incomplete-element-type)

Comment: @user2980564 You should not `#define x`.. it is legal but now you can't use 'x' anymore cause it will be replaced by 23.. use a good name something like `#define TERRAIN_SZ_X 23`