# C: array type has incomplete element type error for external array

Tags: c, arrays

In file "cerberOS_BSP.h" I have the following:

```
extern char cmp_ids[][];
extern UInt8 periph_list[];
```

In file "BSP_unpnp.c", I have:

```
UInt8 periph_list[AMOUNT_OF_PERIPH] = {0};
char cmp_ids[MAX_CMPS][4] = {0};
```

This gives no errors for periph_list but gives the following for cmp_ids:

```
../../uJ/cerberOS_BSP.h:55:13: error: array type has incomplete element type
 extern char cmp_ids[][];
```

Unsure on how to solve this since I don't fully understand the issue, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC: array type has incomplete element type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003270/gcc-array-type-has-incomplete-element-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of …

```
char cmp_ids[][];
```

… you have two dimensions with open (unspecified) size. Since the location of an element is calculated by `start + index * sizeofelements`, it is necessary to know the size of the elements.

The element of the outer array is the inner array `char[]`. The size is not known.

You can only omit the most outer size. All other sizes have to be specified.

Comment: Assuming by "omit the most outer size" you mean the indice that comes first.  myarray[ ][123] is valid, myarray[123][ ] is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

An array must be declared with a size, for instance:

```
extern char cmp_ids[MAX_CMPS][4];
extern UInt8 periph_list[AMOUNT_OF_PERIPH];
```

Therefor, in the header file you need to add (or include) the definitions of MAX_CMPS and AMOUNT_OF_PERIPH. If the sizes need to be calculated at run-time you can instead use pointers:

```
extern char **cmp_ids;
extern UInt8 *periph_list;
```

Comment: The declaration can omit the size of the most outer dimension. Therefore there is no error for `periph_list`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad That's correct. However, without the size of the first dimension there is no way to tell the length of the array in the client module; sizeof is not applicable to incomplete types like UInt8[].